# How to uninstall application programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I tried [this](http://abhi.dcmembers.com/blog/2009/03/17/uninstallation-from-c/),[this](https://sites.google.com/site/msdevnote/home/programmatically-uninstall-programs-with-c) to uninstall the application programmatically. I am not getting any error or exception but the application is not uninstalled from my machine. Please see tried code also

```
public static string GetUninstallCommandFor(string productDisplayName)
{
    RegistryKey localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
    string productsRoot = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products";
    RegistryKey products = localMachine.OpenSubKey(productsRoot);
    string[] productFolders = products.GetSubKeyNames();

    foreach (string p in productFolders)
    {
        RegistryKey installProperties = products.OpenSubKey(p + @"\InstallProperties");
        if (installProperties != null)
        {
            string displayName = (string)installProperties.GetValue("DisplayName");
            if ((displayName != null) && (displayName.Contains(productDisplayName)))
            {
                string uninstallCommand =(string)installProperties.GetValue("UninstallString");

                return uninstallCommand;
            }
        }
    }

    return "";        
}
```

Please help me to uninstall the application programmatically using C#.

Comment: Did you try debugging to see if your `productDisplayName` string was ever matched inside your loop? Did you try debugging at all? By doing this, you can print the names of every product and search if yours is correct (typo, space replaced by underscore, etc...).

Comment: @Kilazur Yes it is matching and went into the if condition but safari is not uninstalled.Please help me.

Comment: So what do you do with `uninstallCommand` ? What does it look like?

Comment: As @Alex points out, this method doesn't uninstall by itself, as far as I can tell. It returns a `uninstallCommand`, which has to be used somewhere else to actually perform uninstallation.

Comment: @AlexK. Can you please tell me how to perform the uninstallation.

Comment: A bit of reseach lead me to [this interesting topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297814/executing-uninstallstring-using-c-sharp) which seems to has a connection to yours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1270830

Comment: @Kilazur i tried your sample,not working for me,can you guide me how to uninstall with the use of uninstallCommand.

Comment: Can anyone help me in solving this,seems i am not getting any error but application is not uninstalled.I tried most of all the solution from google.

Comment: Try to use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (for x64 applications) or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (for x86 applications) instead the `Product` subkeys. Also, check if you can uninstall the application manually using the command contained on corresponding registry value. Is it possible that does not uninstall the application?

Comment: @HuorSwords Can you tell me how to uninstall application manually using command contained on registry value.

Comment: @user2681579 just cupy the `UninstallString` value and execute it from a `cmd` or `Powershell` console. If after executing it, the applications is no longer installed, then you can try to uninstall it (after re-installing, of course) programatically.

Comment: @HuorSwords If i run the command in cmd,it is showing the screen for repair or remove.On clicking remove,successfully remove the application.Can you tell me how to do this prorgramatically.I am getting the uninstallString in uninstallCommand in my question.Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: @user2681579 I don't think you can force a remove this easily, you will end up seeing the repair/remove screen anyway. Imagine what kind of nasty application could be done if you could silently uninstall anything you want. That being said, this is not my domain of expertise, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @HuorSwords I made the uninstall code worked,but it showing the repair/remove screen.I need to hide that screen and do the uninstallation backend.Any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The above routine will return a string, assuming it found a match that may look like:

`MsiExec.exe /X{02DA0248-DB55-44A7-8DC6-DBA573AEEA94}`

You need to take that and run it as a process:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(uninstallString);`

**Note** that it may not be always msiexec, it can be anything that the program chooses to specify. In case of msiexec, you can append `/q` parameter to your `uninstallString` to make it uninstall silently (and it won't show those Repair/Remove dialogs).

**Update**: If you're using Windows installer 3.0 or above, you can also use `/quiet` for silent install/uninstall. It's basically same as `/qn` (if you're on older versions). [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/standard-installer-command-line-options#drawer). Thanks @JRO for bringing it up!

Comment: "/q"  is not showing Repair/Remove screen but the application is not uninstalled and in screen,Repair option is selected by default.

Comment: See if uninstall string contains `/x` or `/f`. /f is used for repair. If it contains /f, then you can manually replace it /x before executing it. It may help to do a dry run from command line. Also, if UAC is required, you need to pass that in Process.Start.

Comment: This is working apart from installer.cs,i want to uninstall 2 application during the installation process of my current application.So i called this uninstall process in installer.cs in beforeuninstall method.When i called this at installer.cs it is not uninstalling the applicationIt is showing the screen as "Preparing to uninstall" and that screen closes suddenly.But apart from installer.cs it is working.Any idea how to debug and what might be the problem of not uninstalling the application when the uninstaller method is called in installer.cs.

Comment: No idea. You can try adding `/l*v uninstall.log` flag and look at the generated logfile to see what's causing the failure.

Comment: You need to use "/quiet" in order to silently uninstall.

Comment: @JRO /q is a short version of /quiet. Or has that changed recently?

Comment: Something changed I guess, when I use just "/q" it showes the MSIExec helper with the available commands

You should use "/q" like 
msiexec /q{n | b | r | f | n+ | b+ | b-}

Comment: Oh yeah that's a newer option. `/quiet` is basically `/qn`. `/q` was always meant to be used with one of those choices to control how much quiet you want it to be. I'll update the answer to note this.

Comment: the returned string will not always be `/X {ProductKey}`. So this solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `UninstallString` property is not enough to uninstall the product.
According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstall-registry-key) the property means:

> UninstallString Determined and set by Windows Installer.

This means the string can be `Msiexec.exe /I{someProductKey}`. This will not uninstall anything. However, it help you to get the **productKey**. running in *prompt command* or *powershell* `msiexec.exe /?` will display the options. There you can see how to uninstall a product.

In order to get the **productKeyCode** You can do this in many ways, but just as example using regular expression:

```cs
var uninstallCommand = (string)installProperties.GetValue ("UninstallString");
var productKey       = Regex.Match (uninstallCommand, @"\{([^(*)]*)\}").Groups[0].Value;

// Once you get the product key, uninstall it properly.
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ();
processInfo.Arguments       = $"/uninstall {productKey} /quiet";
processInfo.CreateNoWindow  = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.FileName        = "msiexec.exe";
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (processInfo);
```

Maybe inside your `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData"` can have more than one folder and your product will be not found if you just hard code the folder name. Just loop into it like:

```cs
var localMachine    = Registry.LocalMachine;
var userDataRoot    = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData";
var userData        = localMachine.OpenSubKey (userDataRoot);
string[]    userDataFolders = userData.GetSubKeyNames ();
foreach (var folder in userDataFolders)
{
   var productsRoot   = @$"{userDataRoot}\{folder}\Products";
   var products       = localMachine.OpenSubKey (productsRoot);
   string[]    productFolders = products.GetSubKeyNames ();
   foreach (string p in productFolders)
   {
      // code
   }
```